# remove song (URL) from iTunes library using AppleScript on OSX

Tags: streaming, applescript, itunes

I am controlling iTunes via AppleScript and am adding URLs to the main library (via `open location "http://..."`).

Is there a way to remove that entry from the library using AppleScript? The URL is very unique so I do not worry about deleting other entries of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set myUrls to get every URL track
    repeat with aUrl in myUrls
        if (aUrl's address as text) starts with "http://shiva.6o4.net:" then delete aUrl
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: awesome, that does the job. Do you by any chance know whether I could add such a script as a hook? Basically would love to have a track removed when playback ends (i.e. connection is closed or next song is being played)

Comment: The function Tom Cruise receiving directions. :)